# javascript: use variable from one file in other

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

So, I am building a pretty complicated plugin and ran into a snag. (This is how I learn though, so snags are good...) My code looks similar to the following:

**Document 1**

```
if( !window.TextEdit ){
  var TextEdit = {"version": "1.0"};
}

TextEdit.edit = function(context, options) {
    var self = this;
    self.context = context;

    self.buttonDef = {
        bold: {
            class: 'bold',
            command: 'bold',
            icon: 'bold',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: ''
        },
        italic: {
            class: 'italic',
            command: 'italic',
            icon: 'italic',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: ''
        },
        underline: {
            class: 'underline',
            command: 'underline',
            icon: 'underline',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: ''
        }
    }

    self.init();
}
```

**Document 2**

```
if( !window.TextEdit.imageload ){
  TextEdit.imageload = {"version": "1.0"};
}

TextEdit.imageload = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.editor = TextEdit;

    self.init();
}

TextEdit.imageload.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        var self = this;

        console.log(self.buttonDef);

        $('.tdt-btn-addimage').click(function() {



        });


    },
    create: function() {

    },
    destroy: function() {

    }   
}

new TextEdit.imageload();
```

So, using Document 2 I want to access the variable self.buttonDef in Document 1. I am able to access the functions in Document 1 just fine, but not the variables.

What I am looking for is how to make `buttonDef` a property of `TextEdit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make buttonDef a property of TextEdit using the below code.

```
TextEdit.buttonDef = {
        bold: {
            class: 'bold',
            command: 'bold',
            icon: 'bold',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: ''
        },
        italic: {
            class: 'italic',
            command: 'italic',
            icon: 'italic',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: ''
        },
    underline: {
        class: 'underline',
        command: 'underline',
        icon: 'underline',
        type: 'checkbox',
        label: ''
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem is that`self` is inside of the function `edit`, and so cannot be accessed at the scope of your second document. Consider having your `edit` function return the object `self` that it creates, store that as a variable, and then call `var.buttonDef`.

Comment: I'm trying to return self and access it, but I'm not getting any results. Could you give me an example?